# Finding Fibonacci bugs keep returning undefined

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, series, fibonacci

I am trying to solve the fibonacci in recrusive way and I think i got a bug in my code.I can't figurer out where it is.
Example:
 fib(4) === 3

```
function fib(n, array = [0, 1], count = 0) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (n == 1) {
    return 1;
  }

  array.push(array[count] + array[count + 1]);
  console.log(array)

  if (n === array.length-1) {

    return array.pop()
  }
  fib(n, array, count + 1);
}
let ans=fib(2)
console.log(ans)
```

Comment: You can solve this problem without `array` and `count`. You have your two base cases, `n == 0` and `n == 1` and that's all you need. Remember that `fib(n)` is simply the sum of `fib(n-1)` and `fib(n-2)`, so `fib(2)` = `fib(1) + fib(0)` = `1 + 0` = `1`. No idea what you need the extra parameters for.

Comment: looks as if you took an array cached iterative solution and tried to jam it into a recursive solution

Comment: You're just missing a `return` in the last line of the function.

Answer (score 1):

you can do by this way using recursion

```js
  var i = 0, a = 0, b = 1, c = 0;
  var out = "";
 
  function fibonacci(n){
    i = 0;
    if(i < n){
     out += a + ",";
     c = a + b;
     a = b;
     b = c;
     i++;
     console.log(out);
     fibonacci(n - i); 
   }
  }

  fibonacci(10);
```